Apache Flink CEP with optional event not work as expected
I have this pattern:
Pattern<Event, ?> pattern = Pattern.<Event>begin("A", AfterMatchSkipStrategy.noSkip())
                .where(new IterativeCondition<>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(Event value, Context<Event> ctx) {
                        return value.getType().contains("A");
                    }
                })
                .next("B").where(new IterativeCondition<>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(Event value, Context<Event> ctx) {
                        return value.getType().contains("B");
                    }
                })
                .next("C").where(new IterativeCondition<>() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean filter(Event value, Context<Event> ctx) {
                        return value.getType().contains("C");
                    }
                })
                .optional()
                .within(Duration.ofSeconds(10));

I want event C to be optional. My input stream:
DataStream<Event> eventStream = env.fromData(
                        new Event(1, "A"),
                        new Event(1, "B"),
                        new Event(1, "C")

                )
                .assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(new IngestionTimeExtractor<>());

And sink:

PatternStream<Event> patternStream = CEP.pattern(eventStream.keyBy(Event::getId), pattern);

SingleOutputStreamOperator<MatchedEventsContainer> eventsBuildStream = patternStream
                .process(new EventsToContainerPPF());


        eventsBuildStream.addSink(new SinkFunction<>() {
                    @Override
                    public void invoke(MatchedEventsContainer value, Context context) {
                        log.debug(">>> sink: {}", value);
                    }
                });

I added the output to the object's log, which contains all the matched events.
In log, I see this:
>>> sink: OptionalEventTestJob.MatchedEventsContainer(events={A=[OptionalEventTestJob.Event(id=1, type=A)], B=[OptionalEventTestJob.Event(id=1, type=B)]})
>>> sink: OptionalEventTestJob.MatchedEventsContainer(events={A=[OptionalEventTestJob.Event(id=1, type=A)], B=[OptionalEventTestJob.Event(id=1, type=B)], C=[OptionalEventTestJob.Event(id=1, type=C)]})

As you can see, sink was called two times, in the first case for A and B, in the second case for A, B, and C.
But I expected to see only one line, which will have A, B, and C events.  And if event C is not present in the incoming stream, then only A and B.
Why is there a two-time output, and how do I get the expected result?
